# Return 0 if no record found for some dates in a UNION query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(c.ID) as RECORD_COUNT, c.WEEK_START, c.LABEL
FROM
    (SELECT 
         a.ID, TRUNC(a.START_DATE,'IW') WEEK_START, 'YES' as LABEL 
     FROM 
         TABLE1 a
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
         b.ID, TRUNC(b.START_DATE,'IW') WEEK_START, 'NO' as LABEL 
     FROM 
         TABLE1 b
     WHERE 
         FUNCTION(b.ID) = 'Test') AS c
```

What I am getting is the count of records per week, the ones that appeared in the first subquery with a label `YES`, and a count of records per week that appeared in the second subquery with a label `NO`.

Example:

```
RECORD_COUNT   WEEK_START   LABEL
    100          1/28/2019  YES
     24          1/28/2019  NO
     81          2/4/2019   YES
    229          2/11/2019  YES
      6          2/11/2019  NO
```

A lot of times second subquery does not return any records and so I am missing rows for some dates.

In the above example it did not return anything for the row of `NO` for `2/4/2019`.

How can I modify my query to have it return zeros for rows where there is no data?

What I'd like to see is something like this:

```
RECORD_COUNT   WEEK_START   LABEL
    100          1/28/2019  YES
     24          1/28/2019  NO
     81          2/4/2019   YES
      0          2/4/2019   NO
    229          2/11/2019  YES
      6          2/11/2019  NO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend putting the values into columns rather than rows:

```
select trunc(t.START_DATE, 'IW') as WEEK_START,
       count(*) as num_yes,
       sum(case when FUNCTION(b.ID) = 'Test' then 1 else 0 end) as num_nos
from table1
group by trunc(t.START_DATE, 'IW')
order by week_start;
```

If you wanted separate rows, I would then unpivot this:

```
with t as (
      select trunc(t.START_DATE, 'IW') as WEEK_START,
             count(*) as num_yes,
             sum(case when FUNCTION(b.ID) = 'Test' then 1 else 0 end) as num_nos
      from table1
      group by trunc(t.START_DATE, 'IW')
     )
select (case when l.label = 'YES' then t.num_yes else t.num_nos end) as record_count,
       t.week_start, l.label
from t cross join
     (select 'YES' as label from dual union all select 'NO' as label) l
order by week_start;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more complex ways to do it that will work more generally.  But for your case a simple way is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.ID) as RECORD_COUNT, c.WEEK_START, c.LABEL
FROM
(
    SELECT a.ID, 
           TRUNC(a.START_DATE,'IW') WEEK_START, 
           'YES' as LABEL 
    FROM TABLE1 a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DECODE(FUNCTION(b.ID),'Test',b.ID,NULL) ID,
           TRUNC(b.START_DATE,'IW') WEEK_START, 
           'NO' as LABEL 
    FROM TABLE1 b
) as c
```